# How to get only alphabets from string in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table "Temp". I want to extract only alphabets from the below table and want output as below:
**col**

```
ABC123
456CDE
F789GH
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ABC
CDE
FGH
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: In Postgres or Oracle use `regexp_replace()`

Answer (score 3):

If using a database which supports `REGEXP_REPLACE`, then use this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '\d', '', 'g') FROM yourTable;
```

The above is the call you would make for Postgres, for Oracle you don't need the `g` greedy flag as the replacement will be greedy by default.

If using a database without regex replacement support, e.g. MySQL or SQL Server, then we can still replace each digit individually:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '9', ''), '8', ''), '7', '')  -- ... replace 1-6 also
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using oracle so REGEXP_REPLACE can be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using oracle you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'[0-9]','') FROM Temp
```

Comment: Thanks. Its really helpful